# How can i fix this issue TypeError: 'SMTP_SSL' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

How can i fix this error in python TypeError: 'SMTP_SSL' object is not callable

this is a function

```
import smtplib, ssl


def show_im_having_fun():

 return

smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=ssl.create_default_context()).login('hello@gmail.com', 'pass')

smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=ssl.create_default_context())('email@gmail.com',"receemail",  message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format('this is subject', """\ Hello World """))

print("sent")
```

and i am importing and calling this function like this in other file

```
from fun import show_im_having_fun

 show_im_having_fun()
        print(show_im_having_fun())
```

Comment: Most of your code isn't even in the function body, and this isn't how you use the smtplib library. Check a tutorial to see the proper way of sending an email.

Comment: @SuperStormer i am not a python dev can you give me code examples

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-send-email/

Comment: @SuperStormer its confusing to me Can you give me a code example here

Comment: @SuperStormer The linked resource documents the Python 3.2 API; you will want to link to something which documents the 3.3+ version.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in some other programming languages, you can't chain the object's initializer like that; the error message tells you as much.

Code which is not inside a `def`  or `class` or similar will run when you `import` that file, which is probably not what you want here. The immediate fix would be to move your SMTP code to a different file, and only leave the function you actually wanted to `import` in this file.

(Also, the function will simply return `None` so that's what you end up printing. But I suspect this code is trimmed down to such a minimal form that discussing it is pointless.)

If I am able to guess what you are actually trying to do with `smtplib`, this should be a minimal fix:

```
# Probably don't stack multiple imports on the same line
# but we don't really need ssl here anyway
import smtplib


with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as server:
    server.login('hello@gmail.com', 'pass')
    server.sendmail(
        'email@gmail.com', "receemail", 
        message='Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format('this is subject', """\ Hello World """))

print("sent")
```

Assembling an SMTP message by pasting together strings like that is extremely error-prone, though; you'll want to use the `email.message.EmailMessage` class going forward;

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib


message = EmailMessage()
message["from"] = 'email@gmail.com'
message["to"] = "receemail"
message["subject" ] = 'this is subject'
message.set_content("""\ Hello World """)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as server:
    server.login('hello@gmail.com', 'pass')
    server.send_message(message)

# probably don't
# print("sent")
```

This seems a bit more verbose, but it is also hugely more robust; your simple attempt will work fine if all you need is a few short lines of English text, but breaks with a fanfare and big explosions if you try to send non-English text, rich content, attachments, or etc.

As an aside, many on-line tutorials about sending email from Python which you find on the Internet are obsolescent. The `email` library was overhauled in Python 3.6 (which is when it became official; the code was introduced already in 3.3 as optional) and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical than the `MIMEBase` etc examples you will often find in search engines and on tutorial sites. A good intro for many use cases is in the current [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)